# How to use select query inside max function?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, max

May I know the reason why this below query is not valid?

```
select * from shop where price = max(select price from shop);
```

I am trying to get the maximum price column in shop table, so in where clause I am comparing the price with max price from the query set.

I know that the syntax of max will not allow this, but are there any reasons for max to do not take query set as the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression on the the right side of the equality is invalid. `max()` is an aggregate function, that need to be `select`ed. That would be:

```
select * from shop where price = (select max(price) from shop);
```

This gives you rows in `shop` that have the top `price`, and includes ties if any.

Note that if you don't need to allow top ties the query can be simplified as follows:

```
select * from shop order by price desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Why is this not valid?  For two reasons:

First, `max()` is not allowed in the `where` clause.  Second, you have a subquery that returns returns multiple values -- however, that is not allowed, even for an aggregation function.

The `max()` needs to go into the subquery, turning it into a *scalar subquery* -- that is, a subquery that returns one column and 0 or 1 rows:

```
select s.*
from shop s
where s.price = (select max(s2.price) from shop s2);
```

If you want only one row returned, a simpler method is:

```
select s.*
from shop s
order by s.price desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it other way around:

```
select * from shop where price = (select max(price) from shop);
```